# Which packages to install to get Transmission torrent client?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I've been using Linux for a few days. I performed a minimal Ubuntu 18.10 installation, and am now looking to install Transmission via Terminal. An `apt-cache search transmission` showed me these packages:

```
transmission - lightweight BitTorrent client
transmission-common - lightweight BitTorrent client (common files)
transmission-cli - lightweight BitTorrent client (command line interface)
transmission-daemon - lightweight BitTorrent client (daemon)
transmission-gtk - lightweight BitTorrent client (GTK interface)
transmission-qt - lightweight BitTorrent client (Qt interface)

(Copied from some random website since I am on my Windoze PC. The result should be similar.)
```

The `transmission-cli`, `transmission-gtk`, and `transmission-qt` should be self-explainatory. What's about the others? What do they suppose to do when installed separately? Or maybe they're just dependencies for other packages? I see a lot of tutorial which instruct the user to install using `sudo apt-get install transmission`, but I am not confident to try it yet.

Comment: If you look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/transmission  you'll see the dependencies for `transmission`.  The '-gtk' is used for GNOME, MATE & GTK+ based desktops, the '-qt' used for KDE/LXQt & Qt based desktops.  *GTK+ is the gimp+gnome toolkit, Qt the Q toolkit; two major toolkits used for GUI apps*

Comment: @guiverc I did a little C++ a few years ago so I know these toolkits. So, basically if I am using Ubuntu cosmic with default Gnome desktop, using `apt-get install transmission` will result in `transmission`, `transmission-common` and `transmission-gtk` being installed?

Comment: Yep, sorry I don't know https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/transmission-daemon (daemon) package so can't be more descriptive on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the desktop Transmission client on a GTK based desktop e.g. regular Ubuntu, Ubuntu MATE etc.:

```
sudo apt install transmission-gtk
```

This will also install `transmission-common` as a dependency, amongst other things.

For more details see:

```
apt show transmission-gtk
```

Comment: What would happen if I use `sudo apt-get install transmission` instead? I guess the result will be the same as `transmission-gtk`. But does this mean the `transmission` package is just a container/wrapper, whose job is just selecting the correct package for current desktop environment?

Comment: That should work also. `transmission` is a metapackage that depends on one of the front-end alternatives i.e. `transmission-gtk`, `transmission-qt` or `transmission-cli` etc. In your case `transmission-gtk`...

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the `apt show` command. I've got some confusion between `steam` and `steam-installer` as well, but it was clear after using that command to view the description of each package. Being a Windows user for a long time, I am always cautious before installing anything.

Comment: No problem, I can see why it could be confusing for a new user. Often the info you need is there - it's knowing where to look sometimes that can be the problem.